# Help identifying silver oval capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, repair, damage

[Edited to stay on topic]

My induction hob recently went 'pop'. I believe I have a blown capacitor. "C24" on the main board. It is showing subtle 'bubbling' at the end.

My issue is that I have never seen such a capacitor - if it is indeed a capacitor. It has an oval cross section, is silvery in colour, has what look like metal dust ends, and seems to have 'ribs' along it. The only markings are "3.3 K 400 N9".

It is possible that another component has failed. Any thought on what went 'pop' would be much appreciated.

Please see the photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, (a) IMHO the component you are asking about is *not* the one which has failed (or at least, it's not the obvious one). Judging by the distribution of soot / magic smoke and its discolouration, the source of the black marks is the transistor / triac closest to relay K3 (I can't see its own designator). Therefore I expect that asking about that capacitor won't lead to success for you, sorry. (b) Please note that while identification questions are allowed here, shopping questions (e.g. "where can I source...") are [off-topic](/help/on-topic). I recommend you [edit] the question & remove that.

Comment: @SamGibson has given a good suggestion of soot-source. Since the "black" device is insulated from heatsink, an alternative failure could possibly be a short-to-heatsink .

Comment: @SamGibson I have edited the question as you suggested. Thank you for the warning. I have had another look and I can see why you suspect the transistor. I noticed 'blistering' at the end of the 'capacitor' but I suppose that could be damage from a failing transistor. Following your observation I will update the images in the question to show a better distribution of damage and soot.

Answer (score 3):

The component that's blown is the rectifier diode attached to the heatsink:

[image: Closeup of damaged component]

By increasing the gamma and contrast of your image, you can see the section of the case which has blown and left a "crater."

I can barely make out the part number on it, but I believe it is an [IXYS DSP25](https://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/L015.pdf) of some variant.

[image: IXYS DSP25]

I recommend removing that part carefully and inspecting it to see if you can determine which specific one it is. You also may need to carefully inspect other components as it may or may not be the only casualty of whatever event led to this failure.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. It seems obvious now!

I have attempted to remove it but it seems to be bonded to the heat sink. I think removing it, being able to identify it, cleaning the heatsink, re-bonding it effectively... and then learning if any other components failed, is all a bit too much. If it were a simple swap, why not? But as it is, and at the risk of damaging more parts or having a repeat failure, I think it's time to just replace the entire board - Then at least I'll have spares if another one goes BANG in future!